# How come a form control with custom validation errors doesn't trigger the `:invalid` pseudo selector?

Tags: css, angular, validation, pseudo-element

I have a form with a custom component in it.

```
<form id="fg" [formGroup]="fg">
  <div class="col-lg">
    <custom-input-text
          name="email"
          type="email"
          required
          formControlName="email"
          autocomplete="on">Email Address
    </custom-input-text>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have validations set up for this email inside of the angular form declaration (inside the component) before the constructor is defined.

```
  fg = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
    ]),
  });
```

I also have some default validations that come with the `type="email"`.  This built in validation gives me css on the inputs.

I am aware of how to change the css for the invalid. My problem is that when the pattern validation is invalid, it doesn't trigger the css pseudo selector: `:invalid`.  Though the built in email validation for angular does trigger that.

Here is some of my css.  the formField class is added dynamically (somewhere over typescript to javascript conversion) into a div that surrounds the custom element.  I can change the css, but essentially I just want to "activate" the css on an element on-condition.

```
.formField input:invalid {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Also, custom component:

```
export declare class CustomInputText implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  private renderer;
  type: string;
  protected _type: string;
  directive: string;
  protected _directive: string;
  disabled: boolean;
  placeholder: string;
  errorMessage: string;
  required: boolean;
  readOnly: boolean;
  name: string;
  val: string;
  el: ElementRef;
  value: string;
  onChange: any;
  onTouched: any;
  setDisabled: any;
  protected _validateType(): void;
  protected _validateDirective(): void;
  ngOnInit(): void;
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void;
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void;
  writeValue(value: any): void;
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void;
  constructor(renderer: Renderer2);
}
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post custom input text component code also notice that formControlName wont work for custom input for that you need to use value accesor/

Comment: I can see why you would want a custom validator, but not a custom input form. You should probably post its code here

Comment: @tblev Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @Michael I don't remember much about this.  If I found an answer I would've posted it on here.  Sorry, but I think you're out of luck on this post.